# Randomly facing this error - SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known

Tags: php, amazon-rds

A laravel 5.7 app running on aws elastie beanstalk env, where db is hosted over rds mysql. Ec2 php ver is 7.4. On this ec2 one phpmyadmin is also accessed. Both laravel and phpmyadmin facing one issue in the application randomly. Randomly means sometimes works fine and sometimes time throws an error eg. 10 to 20 requests work and one may throw an exception.

I get this error from laravel when I debug the exception object-

```
{
"message": "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known",
"exception": "Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOException",
"file": "../vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php",
"line": 50,
"trace": [
    {
        "file": "../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php",
        "line": 67,
        "function": "__construct",
        "class": "Doctrine\\DBAL\\Driver\\PDOConnection",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php",
        "line": 100,
        "function": "createPdoConnection",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\Connector",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php",
        "line": 50,
        "function": "tryAgainIfCausedByLostConnection",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\Connector",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/MySqlConnector.php",
        "line": 24,
        "function": "createConnection",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\Connector",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/ConnectionFactory.php",
        "line": 182,
        "function": "connect",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\MySqlConnector",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "function": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\ConnectionFactory",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
        "line": 916,
        "function": "call_user_func"
    },
    {
        "file": "../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseManager.php",
        "line": 248,
        "function": "getPdo",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connection",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseManager.php",
        "line": 234,
        "function": "refreshPdoConnections",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\DatabaseManager",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/DatabaseManager.php",
        "line": 168,
        "function": "reconnect",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\DatabaseManager",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "function": "Illuminate\\Database\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\DatabaseManager",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
        "line": 754,
        "function": "call_user_func"
    },
    {
        "file": "../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
        "line": 768,
        "function": "reconnect",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connection",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
        "line": 616,
        "function": "reconnectIfMissingConnection",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connection",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
        "line": 333,
        "function": "run",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connection",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php",
        "line": 2027,
        "function": "select",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connection",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php",
        "line": 2015,
        "function": "runSelect",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php",
        "line": 2499,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php",
        "line": 2016,
        "function": "onceWithColumns",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php",
        "line": 516,
        "function": "get",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php",
        "line": 500,
        "function": "getModels",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Concerns/BuildsQueries.php",
        "line": 77,
        "function": "get",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php",
        "line": 52,
        "function": "first",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php",
        "line": 131,
        "function": "retrieveById",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Auth\\EloquentUserProvider",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/GuardHelpers.php",
        "line": 60,
        "function": "user",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Auth\\SessionGuard",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/AuthManager.php",
        "line": 292,
        "function": "check",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Auth\\SessionGuard",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php",
        "line": 223,
        "function": "__call",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Auth\\AuthManager",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "../app/Exceptions/Handler.php",
        "line": 57,
        "function": "__callStatic",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade",
        "type": "::"
    },
    {
        "file": "../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php",
        "line": 81,
        "function": "report",
        "class": "App\\Exceptions\\Handler",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "function": "handleException",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions",
        "type": "->"
    }
]
```

}

In the browser, this error looks like this-

```
{
"message": "Server Error"
```

}

---

In phpmyadmin, the below error occurs randomly-

[image: in phpmyadmin getting this and logged out]

---------

This error not logging to my laravel log file, server Apache log file and l=not logging in rds MySQL log. I just get in browsers and users they facing trouble while using the app.

Before a week ago no such issue happened.

I don't get what going wrong with the server. should I need to replace the server machine or software?

Comment: This does not seem to be a prohramming issue, it seems more like either a networking one (routing or name resolution) or an operational one (mysql instance drops)